# gwt-test-utils unit fail when run with jacoco

Tags: sonarqube, gwt-test-utils

We are attempting to generate coverage reports for our GWT application from a set of unit tests written using gwt-test-utils. The project is a multi-module maven project. We are using the sonar-plugin on jenkins in order to generate and collate our coverage and violation information.

When the build jobs run all the GWT unit tests pass as part of the normal build, however when the Sonar plugin attempts to rerun the tests they all fail with the following error:

> initializationError(uk.co.card.gwt.retailpost.client.dialog.productmodify.CurrencyEditDialogTest)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
>   com.googlecode.gwt.test.exceptions.GwtTestException: Error while generating gwt-test-utils prerequisites
>       at com.googlecode.gwt.test.internal.GwtFactory.(GwtFactory.java:113)
>       at com.googlecode.gwt.test.internal.GwtFactory.initializeIfNeeded(GwtFactory.java:45)
>       at com.googlecode.gwt.test.internal.junit.AbstractGwtRunner.(AbstractGwtRunner.java:30)
>       at com.googlecode.gwt.test.GwtRunner.(GwtRunner.java:19)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>       at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
>       at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>       at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>       at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:250)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
>   Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.checkForSeedTypes(ModuleDef.java:559)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:363)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:354)
>       at com.googlecode.gwt.test.internal.GwtFactory.createCompilationState(GwtFactory.java:151)
>       at com.googlecode.gwt.test.internal.GwtFactory.(GwtFactory.java:106)
>       ... 25 more

Looking through the rest of the console output from jenkins, and the workspace directories, I can't locate the log file that the "com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)" refers to.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem and knows how to get Sonar to run the gwt-test-utils successfully, or at least will have an idea when to look to find the previous log entries mentioned in the exception.

**EDIT: After further experimentation the issue appears to be being caused by jacoco. trying to run just the unit tests instrumented with jacoco (and with no sonar involved) results in the same error**

---

**EDIT:

sample from pom.xml

```
    <build>
pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.6.2.201302030002</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12.4</version>
                    <configuration>                        
                        <excludedGroups combine.self="override" />
                        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                        <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m ${jacoco.agent.argLine}</argLine>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
</plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyName>jacoco.agent.argLine</propertyName>
                    <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}</destFile>
                    <append>true</append>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>*.osgi.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>*.apache.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>*.sourceforge.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>*.junit.*</exclude>
                        <!-- Test support code does not need to be covered -->
                        <exclude>uk.co.card.retailpost.clientintegration.utilities.*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <classDumpDir>temp/classes</classDumpDir>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>   
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: After debugging I discover, that problem is with maven + jacoco. If you run jacoco from eclipse (ecl emma plugin) - you will see code coverage report.

Comment: We need the job to run as part of a nightly jenkins build job that's using sonar to report the resulting coverage stats. Any idea how we could generate the coverage, and then reuse it in maven/sonar in that set up?

The application is built in netbeans, due to problems we had with the org.apache.osgi framework in eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in comments libraries are loaded in different order for jacoco with maven-surefire-plugin. To solve this problem write your own runner (extends com.googlecode.gwt.test.GwtRunner) and change classloader for thread  contextClassLoader.

```
import com.googlecode.gwt.test.GwtRunner;

    public class MyGwtRunner extends GwtRunner {

        static {
            URLClassLoader classLoader = (URLClassLoader) MyGwtRunner.class.getClassLoader();

            try {
                URL[] urls = getClassPath();
                ClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls, classLoader);
                Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(cl);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }

        }

        public MyGwtRunner(Class<?> clazz) throws Throwable {
            super(clazz);
        }

        private static URL[] getClassPath() throws MalformedURLException {
            String classPath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
            String pathSeparator = System.getProperty("path.separator");
            String[] array = classPath.split(pathSeparator);

            List<URL> files = new ArrayList<URL>();
            for (String a : array) {
                files.add(new File(a).toURI().toURL());
            }
            return files.toArray(new URL[files.size()]);
        }

    }
```

In your tests override GwtRunner by MyGwtRunner

```
@GwtModule("com.my.module.GwtTestUtils")
@RunWith(MyGwtRunner.class)
public abstract class AbstractGwtJunit extends GwtTest { 
....
}
```

Comment: Still getting the same problem in the sonar job with this configuration. However I'll try getting jacoco to cover the initial test runs, and setting sonar to reuse the reports.

Will comment once I've tried that.

Comment: I tried it with this using the pom setting I've added to the question above, and I'm still seeing the same error. I had to use the additional argline parameter to get jacoco to try and generate coverage for the gwt-test-utils unit tests.

Comment: I tested it with jenkins only. Build end with success, but report is missing... I will check why.

Comment: maven-surefire-plugin runs tests with minimal classpath. It run GwtRunner class. But the GWT libraries are not loaded to the classpath yet. And it generates the problems. I do not know, why this scenario is only, if you run maven-surefire-plugin with jacoco. If you use jacoco from eclipse/manually all work fine. If you run maven-surefire-plugin without jacoco all work fine too.

Comment: Thanks for your help investigating this, I'll see if I can't use this information to work out a solution.

Comment: Only just discovered you'd editted your original answer to offer a new solution. When I've tried implementing it, I'm getting the following error when running the tests. Is it something you've encountered?

Exception in thread "Timer-0" com.googlecode.gwt.test.exceptions.GwtTestConfigurationException: Cannot find 'web.xml' file ' for GWT module